# Android animation

Tags: android, animation

i m really very fed up coding translate animation.
actually my image is moving from one position to another but it is coming back to its actual position.

can any body here provide me the code to move image from one position to another position without coming back.
 plssssssssssssssssssssssss provide me the sollution.

thanks in ad=vance.

Comment: Maybe you could post your solution first so we can show you where you've made a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for this:

```
anim.setFillEnabled(true);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
```

or in XML

```
android:fillEnabled="true"
android:fillAfter="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

Android animations only provide the transition. You need to code the final "view" yourself. That of course depends on how you implemented the original view in the first place.